# How to create mobile apps using visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have interest on creating mobile apps. So is it possible to create a app using visual studio 2010 ultimate. What is the difference between Visual Studio 2010 Express and visual studio 2010 ultimate.

Comment: About $10k :). Visual Studio Express is free. It has basic developer IDE functions. Ultimate contains a lot more content, templates and tools.

Comment: As for creating mobile apps on VS... yes you can but it would have to be either a) a mobile app written in HTML 5 that can be ported over to other platforms or b) using the Windows Mobile platform only. You cant write for Android or iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what platform you want to make mobile aps - Windows Phone/Android/iOS

For Windows Phone - you can download the [Mobile development SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570) for VS2010 which will allow you to create mobile apps.

As for the difference between versions - content. With Ultimate you have more project templates, tools,supports more programing languages and is paid, while Express is a free version with less content for the more *average user*.

Comment: You mention "Windows Phone/Android/iOS" and then link to Windows Phone SDK, which *can't* build apps for Android or iOS.

Comment: Mobile development SDK  is the only way to create windows mobile apps??
I can't install it because my system has 2gb ram but it need 3gb ram

Comment: I think an alternative is Windows App Studio. Not sure if its free though.

Comment: I have downloaded sdk. Then I have create a MainPage.xaml and Page1.xaml and navigate to page1 from mainpage. But one error is showing. The error is  "the object invoked has disconnected from its clients".

Comment: create a new question and provide more details